# How to pass the second argument in antD select onChange?

Tags: reactjs, antd

1. I want to access id of select in onchange.  I'm trying something
   like below  . The second argument needs to be object according to
   documentation
2. Also how to delete this particular select-dropdown by clicking on
   delete

```
 var arr = [];
        var x = NameCount
        while (x > 0) {
          console.log(x)
           arr.push(
            <div style={{width:"100%" , minWidth:'5px', marginRight:'0.5rem'}} >
              <Select id={x-1} style={{ width: "100%" , minWidth:'5px'}} placeholder="Group name" onChange={(e,{key:id})=>handleGroupByname(e,{key:id})}>
                {dropdown_values.map((y) => (
                  <Option key={y}>{y}</Option>
                ))}
              </Select>
             <span onClick={handleDelete}>delete<span>
            </div>
          );
          x--;
        }
        return arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

For onchange you can do:

```
const handleGroupByname = (value, selectId) => {
  // do your stuff here
}

...
...

<Select id={x-1} onChange={(value)=>handleGroupByname(value, x-1)}>
...
...
</Select>
```

For delete, you can apply the same idea

```
const handleDelete = (e, id) => {
  // find the id and
  // remove the item from you arr
}
```

`<span onClick={(e) => handleDelete(e, x-1)}>delete<span>`